# Black screen in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

ok, like an idiot, in Interface Builder i started messing around with the connections and deleted a few connections (ie. delegates, controllers) and now when i build and run, all i get is a black screen. I know you cant see my code but could someone guess at what i would need to reinstate to get a working app back!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First guess would be that the window outlet is not connected. Then I'd check all the other connections that should be there.

Oh, and use a source control management system, i.e. git. :-)

Comment: +1 Source control source control source control! svn, mercurial, git even cvs or (horrors!) vss. JUST DO IT.

Comment: looked into source control...bit daunting at the moment for me!

Comment: For the total noobs that hit this problem what you need to do to get to the outlet is to double-click on the .xib file, then click on the Window object in the inspector, then press ⌘2 (which brings up the connections pane), then click and drag from the circle labeled "New Referencing Outlet" and draw the line to your App Delegate.  A little selection drop down will pop up labeled "window", click on it and then you'll see that in the "Referencing Outlet" you now have a connection between window and your applicaiton delegate.  Not intuitive!